# Merged records based on delimiter - Linux

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Need to parse a file and to create a new file based on the following criterias:

this is the sample source data

```
TTTTT001:866:           $READ #R1         FILE (TEST-ACCOUNTS) LOGICAL               00085100
TTTTT001-867-            USING DESCRIPTOR (COMM-ACCOUNTS)                            00085200
TTTTT001-868-            STARTING FROM COMM-ACCOUNTS = WS-ACCT-KEY                   00085300
TTTTT001-869-            RECORD (TEST-ACCOUNTS) RELEASE(NO).                         00085400
TTTTT001-870-                                                                        00085500
TTTTT001-871-           IF NOT (LAST-RESPONSE-CODE = 0 OR 3)                         00085600
TTTTT001-872-             MOVE 122 TO ERROR-ABEND-CODE                               00085700
TTTTT001-873-             PERFORM ZT-ERROR.                                          00085800
--
TTTTT001:1018:           $READ #R3         FILE (TEST-ACCOUNTS)                       00100300
TTTTT001-1019-                              ISN (R1-ISN)                              00100400
TTTTT001-1020-                           RECORD (TEST-ACCOUNTS)                       00100500
TTTTT001-1021-                          RELEASE (NO) HOLD.                            00100600
TTTTT001-1022-                                                                        00100700
TTTTT001-1023-           IF LAST-RESPONSE-CODE NOT = 0                                00100800
TTTTT001-1024-              OR R3-ISN NOT = R1-ISN                                    00100900
TTTTT001-1025-             MOVE 122 TO ERROR-ABEND-CODE                               00101000
--
```

Looking to get the following

1. each section is identified by --  (results from the grep)
2. remove the numbers appears at the end of each line
3. remove the lines after the . until the --
4. merge the text starting from $READ until the . into a single line

So the output should be like this

```
TTTTT001:866:           $READ #R1         FILE (TEST-ACCOUNTS) LOGICAL USING DESCRIPTOR (COMM-ACCOUNTS) STARTING FROM COMM-ACCOUNTS = WS-ACCT-KEY RECORD (TEST-ACCOUNTS) RELEASE(NO).
--
TTTTT001:1018:           $READ #R3         FILE (TEST-ACCOUNTS) ISN (R1-ISN) RECORD (TEST-ACCOUNTS) RELEASE (NO) HOLD.                    
--
```

Comment: I don't see a question...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this sed command and get your exact result.

```
sed -nr '/[T]+[0-9]+:/{:a;N;/\n--/{p;d;t};/\n.*\./{s/(.*) .*\n[^ ]+-(.*) .*/\1 \2/g;s/ +/ /g;p;d;t};s/(.*) .*\n[^ ]+-(.*) .*/\1 \2/g;s/ +/ /g; t a;}' FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the following code as `sed.in` and then `sed -nr -f sed.in filename`. It works with you sample input on my Ubuntu14.04 with GNU sed version 4.2.2.

I have add comment to this script in case you want to understand and modified it according to your own need. Check [this](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) if you want to learn how to use sed.

```
s/[ \t]*[0-9]*$//;h         # remove trailing number and space, then save it to hold space
:back                       # label
n                           # next line
s/[ \t]*[0-9]*$//           # remove trailing number and space
s/TTTTT[^ ]*[ \t]+(.*$)/\1/ # remove heading and spaces
/\.$/ !{                    # if it's not the line end with '.', append it to hold space
    H
    bback                   # jump to label back
}
/\.$/ {                     # line end with '.'
    H                       # append
    :aa                     # label
    n                       # get next line
    /^--/ !baa              # if it's not line start with '--' skip it
    /^--/ {
        x                   # swap hold space and pattern space
        s/\n/ /g;p          # substitute \n with space and print it
        s/^.*$//            # empty pattern space
        x                   # swap space
        b                   # get into next cycle
    }
}
```